# Flutter_root in iOS not showing

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm having a problem with the iOS folder in my Flutter project. The error I'm getting is Command `PhaseScriptExecution` failed with a nonzero exit code because my flutter_root is not there. How can I add the flutter_root in the User-Defined?

[Here is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJHl.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: do you build/run iOS project?

Comment: Yes, i run and build iOS project. 
The problem I don't have the flutter_root with the sdk path to flutter.and I get this error.
I need to add the missing flutter_root to give the path

Comment: While your are woking on flutter project, neither need to run android nor iOS project seperately. All you need to do is just run the flutter app only. For the flutter_root issue you need to check with the flutter sdk configuration on your machine.